# Access command line parameter in Django admin

Tags: django

How can I access the parameters from command line in **init** method. Eg. "python manage.py get_poll 56" and I want 56 accessible in **init** method.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'poll for voting'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        poll_count(??)

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('poll_count', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Poll_count = options["poll_count"]
```

Comment: I'm not really following why you need this in the `__init__` method. The logic to perform is placed in the `handle` method.

Comment: I know this is a bit odd but there is another method in Command class which is called individually and don't have access to the poll_count other than made available during instantiation. Thanks.